# Some Music Missing on Huawei Tag-L21

Tags: music, huawei

Alright, so I connected my phone to my laptop through a chord and moved a bunch of albums into the Downloads folder on my SD card, and all the music transferred over without a problem. However, when I was checking to see if all the songs were there, 9 songs were missing. I was still able to navigate to all the songs in the fie manager and play them all the way through, but they weren't showing up in the music player. They are all mp3 files. I am using the default music player. It seems to be a problem with the music player, because when I downloaded doubletwist, all the songs were there. I don't wanna switch to using doubletwist though, I wanna keep using the default music player because I prefer it's interface. I think it might be because of the file size, as all the missing songs were under 2000 kb. Please help, this is infuriating me to no end. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be default settings  of music player.try changing settings of that music player.may be the songs which are missing are false recognised as ringtone.